# What's wrong with my 2D array?

Tags: java, arrays

I wrote a code in Java, to match couples in classes (for assignments or sitting or anything), so i used a 2D array.
The BlueJ tells me there is a ArrayOutOfBoundsException in the last loop of my code, and I didn't manage to solve it.
Can anybody tell me how to fix it?

```
    byte pref;
    System.out.println("How many children are in your class");
    byte children = reader.nextByte();
    byte[][] students = new byte[children][children]; //Each cell contains the rank of the match
    System.out.println("Enter each child's preference, according to their number:");
    for (byte b=0;b<students.length;b++)//Ranks each match
    {
        System.out.print((b+1)+") ");
        pref = reader.nextByte();
        pref--;
        students[b][pref]++;
    }
    System.out.println("The matches got 2 points are:");
    for (byte b=0;b<students.length;b++)
    {
        for (byte c=0;c<students.length;b++)
        {
            if (students[b][c]==2)
                    System.out.print(b+"+"+c);
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: You're incrementing `b` in your second loop... did you mean to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Typo error in nested loop
Change

```
for (byte c=0;c<students.length;b++)
```

To

```
 for (byte c=0;c<students.length;c++)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (byte b=0;b<students.length;b++){
  for (byte c=0;c<students.length;/*b++*/c++)
        {
            if (students[b][c]==2)
                    System.out.print(b+"+"+c);
        }
}
```

The OutOfBoundsException is thrown, because you increment b in your second loop, so when the first loop is at its last run, you increment b again and then your out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to the typo you should write **students[b].length**:

```
for (byte b=0;b<students.length;b++){
    for (byte c=0;students[b].length;c++)
    {
        ...
    }
```

, because you want the length of the nested array.